# React concatenate calls after hotreload, is it webpack config?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I've got a method in the React component that retrieves details when component is mount:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    const { loadDetails } = this.props;
    loadDetails();
}
```

After each time I made changes in the component and save it - React hot-reload reloads the component and add 1 more call.

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

After one save, it makes 2 calls all over the app, after two saves - 3 calls.
What may be the reason?

Comment: looks like webpack issue if you are using the one.  Have a look at this https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2983

Comment: This isn't surprising coming from hot reloading. Though, no idea if it can be fixed.

Comment: Maybe the props might change, which triggers remounting the component